# Understanding Dispatcher.RunAsync with an async callback and awaiting UI related tasks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp

I am using C# + UWP for a regular desktop app & create a compatible unity version.
I use several API calls such as MediaCapture.InitializeAsync that must be used from the STA thread.

The code below works on the Desktop app:

```
var ignored = Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Step 1 " + Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess);
    //access STA API calls here
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Debug.WriteLine("Step 2 " + Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess);
    //access STA API calls here
});
```

It will print "Step 1 True" and one sec later "Step 2 True". I assume this means they both run in the UI thread and I can access UI related API calls?

So far this worked well until I triggered the method above via Unity. It will print "Step 1 True" and one sec later "Step 2 False". So it appears after the await call I am no longer on the UI thread.

What exactly is happening here?

Comment: Question: what does `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` return in this case? (in particular, *just before* the await); basically `await` will, by default, resume via sync-context **if there is one**, which is how you normally get back to the UI thread magically; but if there isn't a sync-context, it can't do this

Comment: @MarcGravell it is null if the method is triggered via Unity but an object if triggered via the desktop app. Looks like I have to do some reading about SynchronizationContext. I haven't heard of this yet.

Comment: yup, that explains what you're seeing; I *don't* have a one-line "and here's how you fix it", sorry

Comment: Why not use `UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread` in unity, is it same result?

Comment: @CoCaIceDew It seems to behave the same as Dispatcher.RunAsync. It runs in the UI thread once but switches after the next await call.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on some ancient version of Unity? This used to be a known issue but they fixed it years ago:

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/uwp-messagedialog-class-causes-crash-on-il2cpp-backend